# What is the physical clock ticking inside a living cell?

Tags: time, biophysics, biology

What is the physical process which determines the timescale of the aging of a living cell?

It might be that on the macroscopic scale, i.e., aging of the human, the gravitational force is [one factor](http://science.howstuffworks.com/humans-age-in-space.htm) that sets the timescale of the human age to the order of 100 years. I still need to learn the analogous process in the microscale, i.e., the scale of the cell.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cell physiology

Comment: It seems the OP is looking for a physics idea or concept to be applied to cell biology, so I personally don't have an issue with it.

Comment: @BMS, agree plus indeed there are physics which relate to this area (and some of them are given in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

[Ilya Prigogine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilya_Prigogine) and the school of non-equilibrium thermodynamics has investigated the emergence of structure in chemistry and biology away from equilibrium.

In these cases chemical clocks (and by implication biological clocks) can be seen as complex systems forming structures away from equilibrium. These are refered also as "*TEMPORAL DISSIPATIVE STRUCTURES*" (for example ["BIOLOGICAL RHYTHMS AS TEMPORAL DISSIPATIVE STRUCTURES"](http://www.ulb.ac.be/sciences/utc/ARTICLES/2007_Goldbeter_Adv_Chem_Phys.pdf))

References:

1. Glansdorff, Paul; Prigogine, I. (1971). Thermodynamics Theory of Structure, Stability and Fluctuations.
2. Prigogine, Ilya; Nicolis, G. (1977). Self-Organization in Non-Equilibrium Systems.
3. Prigogine, Ilya (1980). From Being To Becoming. (on [scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/97361975/Ilya-Prigogine-From-Being-to-Becoming-Time-and-Complexity-in-the-Physical-Sciences))